# Aggregation Correlation Strategy based on XML Payload

Tags: aggregate, spring-integration

Issue: How to  correlate messages for an aggregator based on a XML value in the payload? I have a scenerio where I call a third party application and it only gives back an xml response. Based on an xml value in the payload I would like to correlate the messages to produce a single response back to the consumer.

**Example using Header Attribute**

```
@CorrelationStrategy
public Object correlate(Message message) throws JMSException  {         
    return message.getHeaders().get("JMSXUserID");
}
```

**Solution Notes:**

- As described below and referenced in the spring documentation for xml payload support.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xml.html#xpath-spel-function

**Sample Config Applied:**

```
<aggregator
        id="agg"
        input-channel="jmsInChannel"
        output-channel="outputChannel"
        ref="AggregatorPOJO"
        method="combineResponesMessages"
        correlation-strategy-expression="#xpath(payload, '/test/name')"
        release-strategy="AggregatorPOJO"
        release-strategy-method="isComplete"/>
```

This will correlate the following xml.

```
<test><name>test1</name></test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look if `#xpath()` SpEL function can help you, for example:

```
correlation-strategy-expression="#xpath(payload, '/name')"
```

where `payload` is a payload in some XML representation of messages to correlated and `/name` is an `XPath` against that payload.

You should be sure that `spring-integratrion-xml` jar is on your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to parse the XML; you might be able to use a simple regex `Pattern` or you might have to convert the payload to a DOM for more complex situations.